# QTP VB Script to update data excel placed in QC

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to automate some set of test cases which would pass inputs from one to another. For instance, if I have 5 test cases then 1st test case would pass input to 2nd - 2nd to 3rd - likewise it goes on.

And another point to be noted is that I won't perform batch execution and there will be a certain time gap between each test case.

So what I'm trying to do is like updating the outputs into some excel sheet and call them during succeeding execution. I have tried searching and tried some codes, but nothing has worked out.

So please share some idea to update excel sheet during run time which is placed in QC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're essentially saying is that you have test runs separated by some indeterminate amount of time, and you need to share data between runs.  The answer is you need persisted storage of your data.  You could use a database, flat file, Excel spreadsheet, or anything else that will let you programmatically write data in one run then read it in the next.

Excel spreadsheets are one such solution.  You said you tried it and it did not work.  That likely means that the method you used to write or read the data was incorrect, and not that there was a problem with the concept.  If you provide some more specifics about exactly what you tried and where it failed, hopefully the community will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you have Input Excel Sheet(s) in QC, What you can do is download the excel file from QC to local machine, store output from 1st test case to this excel sheet and upload back to QC. Which now you can use as input to next test case.